# isolate objects from each other, angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In my application, I can view, create and update items on a server.
When my page loads, I get items from the server and puts them in an array, I get the ID and Title for each item. 
This array is displayed in a table, and when an title in the table is clicked, I get all attributes for that item with that ID from the server, and displays them for the user.

In my controller I have this:

```
$scope.currentItem = ({
    title: '',
    id: '',
    description: ''
});
```

So, when Viewing and item I would set currentItem like this:

```
// function to get item

$scope.currentItem = ({
    title: item.Title,
    id: item.Id,
    description: item.Description
});
```

Each item also has actions attached to it, so when I view an Item,
 I also get that items related actions, these actions is stored in an array:

```
// function to get Actions

$scope.actionsArray = Actions;
```

In my real application I have many more objects, and several arrays, this is just an example.

But when I am done viewing or creating an item, how should I clear these arrays and objects, so that if I choose to 
view or create another item, I won't have attributes from the previous item in this one?

Right now I have a function like this:

```
$scope.clearItems = function() {
    $scope.currentItem = ({
        title: '',
        id: '',
        description: ''
    });
    $scope.actionsArray = [];
};
```

I call this function after create, update, and viewing of an item. 
But I still feel as if these different items are not isolated from each other, like in some rare case scenario that their attributes can get mixed up, if I choose to update, create and read a lot of items without refreshing the page, which is what I want to achieve.

So my question in short, how can I achieve 'object isolation' in angular?

Comment: make `anguar.copy()`  and `angular.extend()` your friends and keep them in the toolkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can isolate each item in a directive and then isolate the directive scope.
It's pretty easy to do it in angular.

You have an array of item objects in your main controller :

```
$scope.items = [{id:1,title:'title',description:'desc'},...];
$scope.aFunction = function(a,b){return a+b};
```

Main HTML file

```
<my-item data="item" func='aFunction' ng-repeat="item in items"></my-item>
```

Then create a directive

```
app.directive('myItem',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{        //This is what makes your directive scope isolated
            data:'=',  //Think of each attribute as a pipe for data
            func:'&'
        },
        template:'<p>item {{data.id}} : {{data.title}} -> {{data.description}}</p>',
        controller:function($scope){
            // here you can you $scope.data 
            // that contain a reference to your item
            // and the scope is isolated from the others
            // so there is no mixup concerns
            // you can also use $scope.func as a function 
            // in your private scope
        }
    };
});
```

you can now manipule each item separately and also manage them all together by doing manipulation on the `$scope.items` variable in the main controller.

**EDIT :**
This is important to know : When you're using `$scope.data`in your isolated scope each attribute of data is like a direct reference to the item attributes.
Within your isolated scope you **MUST** only modify `$scope.data` attribute and never directly alter `$scope.data` or you will create a local and isolated copy of your item and will break the reference.
For example, you want to pass a boolean to your isolated scope then modify it from the isolated scope :

This is in your main controller

```
$scope.boolean = true;
$scope.anotherBoolean = {value:true};
```

this is your HTML file

```
<my-item bool="boolean" anotherbool="anotherBoolean"></my-item>
```

And in your directive

```
app.directive('myItem',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
            bool:'=',
            anotherbool:'='
        },
        controller:function($scope){
            //this will break the reference and create a local isolated copy of $scope.bool
            $scope.bool = false;
            //this will not
            $scope.anotherbool.value = false
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I thought I was missing, thanks a lot!

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, could you show me an example on how you would edit the title of an item, by letting the user type it in an input?

Comment: Yeah it's pretty simple actually just make an input like this one in your directive template : `<input ng-model="data.title"/>`.  Like so you're modifying the title attribute so nothing gets broken.

Comment: You're welcome Bro =) ! You can learn a lot about isolated scope on youtube there is a [bunch of excellent videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=angular+isolated+scope) about it.